# SPARQL - How to select by individual?

Tags: sparql, owl

When I query like this:

```
SELECT ?subject ?object WHERE { ?subject ont:has_author  ?object}
```

I can get the result:

```
subject:harry potter,object:J.K. Rowling
```

(Note: J. K. Rowling is an individual of class.)

But when I query like this I do not get the result.

```
SELECT ?subject  WHERE { ?subject ont:has_author  J. K. Rowling  }
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: It is always better to give more details about your environement. So that anybody can reproduce your problem. For example : What is your ontology ? where and How do you store your individual ? etc ...

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. One as @fopa-léon-constantin says.

You can ask for the URI for J. K. Rowling or you can search for the name (literal) J. K. Rowling.

Depends a little on what kind of SPARQL query engine you use, but here are the two examples.
The first one depends on you having the URI to J. K. Rowling.

```
SELECT ?subject  WHERE { ?subject ont:has_author  ont:J_K_Rowling}
```

The second is done if you want to search after her name by string.

```
SELECT ?subject  
WHERE { 
       ?subject ont:has_author ?author
       FILTER (str(?author) = "J. K. Rowling")
}
```

You should know which approach you should use by looking at the ontology you are using.
There it is defined if `ont:has_author`has a literal or an URI as object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have solved this problem.

Answer (score -1):

may be because you did not specify the name space of the individual `J. K. Rowling`.

I would have expect your query to be

```
SELECT ?subject  WHERE { ?subject ont:has_author  ont:"J. K. Rowling"}
```

Comment: This query is not legal SPARQL syntax: `ont:"J. K. Rowling"` is not a legal notation for either a URI _or_ a literal value.